# How can I edit php.ini?

Tags: permissions, lamp

I am using lamp on my computer for development only. The problem is that I cannot make any changes to it because the owner is root. How could I change the permissions to it?

Answer (score 6):

Changing the ownership and permissions of system files is not a good idea and can result in this particular case you may be able to "get away" with this change, in general changing ownership and permissions on system files is asking for problems ranging from security to system failures.

You should edit the files as root

```
# Command line
sudo -e /path/to/php.ini

# Graphical
gksu gedit /path/to/php.ini
```

If you do not have root access talk to your system administrator.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RootSudo for further information.

Comment: its helpful....

Answer (score 0):

You can change the owner of file once and then make changes to it as you do to any other file you own. You need to run:

`sudo chown user /path/to/your/file/php.ini`

Where `user` is your username.

To make sure any user on system can read (but not edit it):

`chmod 644 /path/to/your/file/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working/testing a particular application and need the PHP configuration to be changed for that, and in this case you can simply "Sudo" edit that.

If you installed a stack version using either Tasksel or aptitude, the wollowing will work

> sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

If you like you can use gedit as well.

However, if you want to edit/make frequent changes, you can change the file ownership to the userid you use during your development.

You can use,

> sudo chown oli_dev /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

oli_dev being your user name 
and 
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini being your primary php configuration file.

In case you're unsure of the php.ini file used by your interpreter, 
use phpinfo() inside a test script and call it in browser. It should help you locate the configuration file loaded.

Hope this helps, plz do revert if you need more assistance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

to find the file, and then

```
sudo vim /path/to/your/file/php.ini
```

You may also need to edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` or if you're using nginx (which I doubt) `vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

hit <kbd>/</kbd> to search, enter `uploadmaxfilesize` and Enter. Get the pointer to the corresponding value that's set there and hit <kbd>i</kbd>. Delete/Backspace away the value and change it to what you want it to be. Then hit <kbd>esc</kbd>. Continue with search until you've properly edited the file.

Then hit `:wq` to save the file and exit

then restart the whole system to make sure changes apply.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, and as I'm not used to Linux I asked for help and the solution is quite simple. Better than change file's permissions is to edit the file from console making a `sudo` to change your permissions to *root*.

So, you open a task console and put:

```
$ cd /etc/php/7.2/apache2/ <-- assuming this is the path for php.ini. Check PHPInfo().
$ sudo -i
```

Here you will be prompted to enter your user's password. And after this you've become *root* user.

```
# nano php.ini
```

And now add/remove your configuration, save your changes, restart Apache and exit from *root* account:

```
# exit
```